# Convert the whole (large) schema into hdf5

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dask

I am trying to export the whole database schema (around 20 GB) using postgreSQL query to create a final unique hdf5 file.

Because this size don't fit on my computers memory, I am using chuncks argument.

First I use this function to establish conection:

```
def make_connectstring(prefix, db, uname, passa, hostname, port):
    """return an sql connectstring"""
    connectstring = prefix + "://" + uname + ":" + passa + "@" + hostname + \
                    ":" + port + "/" + db
    return connectstring
```

Then I created a temporary folder to save each of hdf5 file.

```
def query_to_hdf5(connectstring, query, verbose=False, chunksize=50000):

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectstring, 
        server_side_cursors=True)    

    # get the data to temp chunk filese
    i = 0
    paths_chunks = []
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
        for df in pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=engine, chunksize=chunksize):
            path = td + "/chunk" + str(i) + ".hdf5"
            df.to_hdf(path, key='data')
            print(path)
            if verbose:
                print("wrote", path)
            paths_chunks.append(path)
            i+=1


connectstring = make_connectstring(prefix, db, uname, passa, hostname, port)
query = "SELECT * FROM public.zz_ges"
df = query_to_hdf5(connectstring, query)
```

What is the best way to merge all these files into 1 single file that represents the whole dataframe ?

I tried something like this :

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    print(path)
    for path in paths_chunks:
        df_scratch = pd.read_hdf(path)
        df = pd.concat([df, df_scratch])
        if verbose:
            print("read", path)
```

However, the memory goes up very fast. I need something that could be more efficient.

### Update:

```
def make_connectstring(prefix, db, uname, passa, hostname, port):
    """return an sql connectstring"""
    connectstring = prefix + "://" + uname + ":" + passa + "@" + hostname + \
                    ":" + port + "/" + db
    return connectstring

def query_to_df(connectstring, query, verbose=False, chunksize=50000):

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectstring, 
        server_side_cursors=True)    

    # get the data to temp chunk filese
    with pd.HDFStore('output.h5', 'w') as store:
        for df in pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=engine, chunksize=chunksize):
            store.append('data', df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [`HDFStore`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html#hdfstore-pytables-hdf5) directly, that way you can append chunks as you get them from the database, something like:

```
with pd.HDFStore('output.h5', 'w') as store:
  for df in pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=engine, chunksize=chunksize):
    store.append('data', df)
```

this is based around your existing code so isn't complete, let me know if it isn't clear

note I'm opening the store in `w` mode so it'll delete the file every time.  otherwise `append` will just keep adding the same rows to the end of the table.  alternatively you could `remove` the key first

when you open the store you also get lots of options like compression to use but it doesn't seem to be well documented, `help(pd.HDFStore)` describes `complevel` and `complib` for me

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer.
See if  my updated example is like you suggested

Comment: When I run this function, the output file is created, but with no data.

Comment: Hi Sam, it was related with dtypes and column sizes issues.

Comment: glad to help!  note that there are various things you can do to make things faster, e.g. various suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084843/1358308

Comment: Hi Sam, I am facing an error: 
server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.

Comment: I added an Try/expect, but I am not sure how to restablish connection

Comment: sounds like a database issue unrelated to HDF5.  I'd suggest trying to isolate the issue and posting a new question when you can get a reproducible test case